# Azure VM with SQL and visual studio

Tags: azure

Is there any VM images available in Azure, with SQL server and Visual studio installed.

I am looking for a VM with builtin SQL server and Visual studio installed.

Comment: That combination doesn't seem to be available in the marketplace. You _could_ take a SQL Server VM image and install Visual Studio community. Or take a Visual Studio VM image and install SQL Express.

Answer (score 0):

The development VMs contain only Visual Studio 2017 pre-installed, Enterprise or Community. If you got a MSDN account you can create Windows 10 machine, otherwise only Windows Server 2016 are available.

If you need a VM with both Visual Studio and SQL server pre-installed, then in my opinion your best best is to create a custom image and upload it to Azure.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-custom-images) page for how to do that.

Comment: id say just install vs to the sql vm, much easier

Comment: how will be the license affect in uploaded images..does it require another license or can I use the on premise license keys...